# Mysql RDS migration problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, aws, amazon-rds

I'm trying to migrate my MySQL RDS to a different machine. The reason is that I need smaller disk, and you can't make disks smaller for RDS servers, only bigger.

I'm trying to migrate with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638012/backup-mysql-amazon-rds#20645291
and this tutorial:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Start.Repl

Briefly :

1. Created replica and stopped
2. Migrated from replica to a new server
3. Created user on Source DB with:

   `CREATE USER 'repl_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'slavepass';`

   `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'%'`
4. I've pointed to master from slave with this command:

   `CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('source.mydomain.com', 3306,'repl_user', 'slavepass', 'mysql-bin-changelog.000001', 107, 0);`
5. I've started replication with :

   `CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;`

When checking status with `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`, it shows that slave can't connect to master.
All servers are in the same security group. I was trying to connect to source with `repl_user` with MySQL command line and it worked. 
I have no idea where to look next. I think it might be something with security in aws, but I was comparing new server with existing replicas and all seems the same.

I'm running MySQL 5.6 on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work with pointing slave to master IP instead of url, and putting slave ip to inbound rules of Master's security group